# List and ReadOnly property

Tags: c#, list, readonly-collection

List (and List) instances can be readonly, seeing ReadOnly property; methods throws exceptions in the case the collection have the property ReadOnly property.

How can I create readonly List instances? What are the main uses?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[ReadOnlyCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132474.aspx)

From the link above:

> "A collection that is read-only is
>   simply a collection with a wrapper
>   that prevents modifying the
>   collection; therefore, if changes are
>   made to the underlying collection, the
>   read-only collection reflects those
>   changes."

So, anytime you need a collection that is not changeable, use this.

Comment: Best way to understand this is to read the dinosaur list example from the link provided by Michael.